# How can I keep my Jabber bot's status online?

Tags: ruby, xmpp

Here is my code:

```
require 'xmpp4r/client'

jid = Jabber::JID::new('some.other@gmail.com/Home')
cl = Jabber::Client::new(jid)
cl.connect
cl.auth('pass')

cl.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_show(:chat).set_status('my_status'))
#cl.send Jabber::Presence::new

salutation = Jabber::Message::new( 'here.again@gmail.com', '' )
salutation.set_type(:chat).set_id('1')
cl.send salutation

while 1
end
```

But when I close chat window jabber-bot goes offline. How can I keep it online?

Comment: Are you just closing the terminal window that Ruby is running in?

Comment: No, I just closing the google talk chat window.